# How does Java sort an Integer Array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```java
public class SortArr {

    public static void sortAsc(int[] arr) {
        int temp = 0; //a variable to store temporary value while swapping
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) { //for loop to hold the current element to be compared
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) { //for loop to iterate over the other elements
                //to get them compared with the current element 
                if (arr[i] > arr[j]) { //if any of the higher index element is smaller than
                                       //the current element
                    temp = arr[i]; //store the current element to temp
                    arr[i] = arr[j]; //store the smaller element to the lower index position
                    arr[j] = temp; //store the current element to greater index position
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int array[] = {5, 3, 1};
        System.out.println( "Array values before sorting:");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]+ "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        sortAsc(array);
        System.out.println( "Array values after sorting:");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i]+ "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Array values before sorting:
5  3  1  
Array values after sorting:
1  3  5
```

I know at first it compares 5 with 3, then 5 with 1, but how does it compare 1 with 3? Can anyone explain it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: This is [exchange sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort).

Answer (score 0):

How Java sorts it, is up to the implementation. You can use `Arrays.sort()`, the documentation states as follows:

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive,
> iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons
> when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the
> performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is
> randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the
> implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage
> requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays
> to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays. The
> implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and descending order
> in its input array, and can take advantage of ascending and descending
> order in different parts of the same input array. It is well-suited to
> merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate the arrays and
> sort the resulting array. The implementation was adapted from Tim
> Peters's list sort for Python ( TimSort ). It uses techniques from
> Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting and Information Theoretic
> Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on
> Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January 1993.

Code example:

```
Integer[] array = {3, 1, 2};
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Your code appears to be a [Bubble Sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) which is generally easier to implement but slower than other sorting algorithms due to `O(n^2)` average performance.

Furthermore, you can use a debugger to see step-by-step how your code is executing.

Note that for code outside of a learning spectrum, it's better to use a built-in sorting API instead as shown above instead of implementing it yourself.

Comment: I believe is it a kind of [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) (easy to get confused, but Bubble Sort uses kind of a flag for "*are repeated until no swaps had to be performed*")

Comment: @user16320675 the flag is an optimization and not necessary for the correctness. The important part for a bubble sort is direct neighbour comparison. One can show that `n` iterations over an array of size `n` with the core bubble sort logic will always result a sorted array.

Comment: @user16320675 I never said that the code presented does what I wrote, just that a bubble sort does this. And yes, `n-1` iterations is the minimum iterations.

Comment: @user16320675 because the statement "*Bubble Sort uses kind of a flag for "are repeated until no swaps had to be performed")*" is not correct.

Comment: You've quoted the impl of Arrays.sort that sorts `Object`, which doesn't apply here. The impl for sorting arrays of primitives, in this case [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)), is not Tim Sort but the dual pivot quick sort, which is slightly faster in the general case because primitives are fungible in Java.